# Liferay application error when trying to access another page

Tags: java, netbeans, liferay, netbeans-7

I am making a Java application for Liferay. *A simple bookstore*. Uploading and displaying the app in Liferay works, but when i try to access other pages then the index page itself I get an error.

This is how my application looks like at the moment. If i for instance click on "All books" in the navigation to the left. I get an error.

[image: Index page]

This is the error I get, as explained earlier. It says "The requested resource was not found." 
""

[image: Error page]

Any help on what to do, would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code you are using for redirecting to other page?

Answer (score 0):

Your first screenshot shows `/web/student-life`, while the second one shows a URL that looks like a servlet URL, not a portlet URL: `/book?action=allBooks`.

Note that - in the portal world - you'll lose control over the URLs and you'll need the portal to generate them to you. This typically means that they'll be a lot more ugly than the one you're seeing. You can gain back control (through "friendly URLs" in Liferay) but I'd consider this a second (or third) thought if you're just beginning developing portlets.

Create your action URL with `<portlet:actionURL .../>` and - for the time being - stay on the same page. Once everything works you can extend this to multiple pages.